# Not showing created blog entries

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to Rails and learning to create a blog using this [tutorial](http://anunorderedlistapart.tumblr.com/post/80272804821/a-blog-on-steroids-souping-up-your-first-rails-blog). On step 10, once I define create and show, after creating a new post in browser I don't see any entries on show with id page. All I see is heading and and blank title and post header.

Following is my controller -

```
class PostController < ApplicationController

def index
end

def new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:posts])
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Show view ---

```
<h1>Show a post</h1>

<p>
    <strong>Title:</strong>
    <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Text:</strong>
    <%= @post.text %>
</p>
```

Route ---

```
RailsBlog::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :post
  root :to => "post#index"
end
```

Form ---

```
<%= form_for :post, url: {action: 'create'} do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

May be this is just a spelling mistake, but since I've recently started learning Rails, I'm unable to resolve this.

Update: I can go to particular id using

```
http://localhost:3000/post/1
```

but am only seeing blank page with view headers

Comment: Could you also show your form template?

Comment: Also, hopefully you've already addressed the simple question of whether there's a `Post` with that `id` or not?

Comment: @AnthonyAtkinson - it would throw ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error.

Comment: Updated with form template and info that you needed

Comment: @BroiSatse Good point. I've been switching between PHP and Wordpress questions too much this morning ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@post = Post.new(params[:posts])
```

It should be `params[:post]` - singular, not plural.

Also note that the best practice with form_for is to pass an object instead of symbol:

```
form_for @post do |f|
```

Then:

1. You don't need to specify url
2. You can reuse the same form for an edit action or create action (if object creation failed due to failing validation)

This however requires to initialize new object in your `new` action:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

UPDATE:

Also your routes are incorrect. When defining plural resources, you need to use plural form (it's more the convention than requirement, but since you're learning stick with it). So change your routes to:

```
resources :posts
```

And rename your controller to `PostsController` (remember to rename file name as well). restart the server and all should work.

ANOTHER UPDATE:

You also need to rename folder `app/views/post` to `app/view/posts`.

AND YET ANOTHER UPDATE:

In rails 4, you are not allowed to mass assign any params which has not been whitelisted using strong parameters. You need to tell rails which fields you allow to be assigned first - this is a security thing. You need to make some changes to your controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    ...
  end

  ...

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

This is the way to tell your controller that you are expecting those attributes from your form and they can be safely assigned.

Comment: I updated my code with your changes and it's blowing up on `post/new` now with error - `NoMethodError at /post/new
undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000105922d80>:0x00000105921f98>`. I am using better_error gems and it's showing on that form template line that you've mentioned here.

Comment: Still no luck. Should I be updating `root :to` in router too? Also, I changed controller to plural form and filename as `posts_controller.rb`. If I go to `http://localhost:3000/posts/new`, error I am getting is - `ActionView::MissingTemplate at /posts/new
Missing template posts/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/RubyRails/railsBlog/app/views"
  * "/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/views"`

Comment: Thanks for being patient, I could see those pages. However show is still empty

Comment: @Aniruddha It will not affect already created posts - they have been saved to db with empty fields. Create a new ones and they should be populated.

Comment: If I create a new one, it fails on controller `@post = Post.new(params[:post])` and would only work if I make it plural, but then also, it shows empty page though

Comment: @Aniruddha - When you make it plural `params[:posts]` is empty, so nothing is assigned (hence no error). It's `params[:post]` which contains all the data. If this is failing, it most likely means that it is trying to assign non-existing attribute, assigning attribute failed for any reason or that you are using rails 3 and your model has no `attribute_accessible :title, :text` line. What error message are you getitng with `params[:post]`?

Comment: On `localhost:3000/posts/new` I submit the form to see page with error - `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError at /posts
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` pointing to line `@post = Post.new(params[:post])
 `

Comment: @Aniruddha  - This is Rails 4 thingy. I'll update an answer in few seconds.

Comment: Any clue on this error, I tried couple of other things mentioned on this site, but nothing useful. Still stuck on it

Comment: @Aniruddha - I have updated answer. 10 hours ago. :)

Comment: Yep. All worked fine and I got to know about [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had just similar problem on the same tutorial.
The code spelling was correct and clearly accorded to examples in tutorial and BroiSatse's answer above.

The mistake was in order of private method definition.
How it was:

```
...
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
...
```

The working order:
`def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end`

private
...

Anyway, this topic was rather helpful. Thak you for your answers!